# SpringBoot SAML SP Shibboleth IDP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shibboleth, opensaml

I am trying to connect and login to [testShib](http://www.testshib.org) IDP using this [Sp Mock](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina) the problem is that when i try to login without the option to sign the authnRequest then i am able to login but i get an error upon redirect.

```
     Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unwrapping failed
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:445)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2549)
        at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1477)
        ... 70 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:502)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:296)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:440)
        ... 72 common frames omitted
 DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Attempt to decrypt EncryptedKey using credential from KEK KeyInfo resolver failed: 
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.DecryptionException: Error decrypting encrypted key
        ERROR o.o.saml2.encryption.Decrypter - SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content 
        org.opensaml.xml.encryption.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData
```

If i try it with the option to sign the authnRequest i get an error in idp

```
 WARN [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml2.SSOProfileHandler:406] - Message did not meet security requirements
    org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed
```

What am i doing wrong i am new to SAML so i am not very familiar with this

Comment: In your shibboleth2.xml did you check whether the certificate is available or not? If yes then it should be same as one attached to metadatafile.